# Format Unix time using Get-Date -UFormat

Tags: powershell, datetime

I'm trying to convert Unix Epoch time to a readable format. See example code:

```
# First convert time to Unix time seconds. 
$time = Get-Date -Hour 12 - Minute 30 -Second 0
([datetimeoffset]$time).ToUnixTimeSeconds()
1552912200
```

All OK. Now I'm trying to format the time in reverse:

```
Get-Date 1552912200 -UFormat %R
00:02
```

This is not correct. Why is `00:02` output? When I am expecting `12:30`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Get-Date` expects a `DateTime` object:

```
Get-Help Get-Date
# Get-Date [[-Date] <DateTime>] ...
```

So the value `1552912200` is implicitly **converted** to `DateTime`, which results in `01.01.0001 00:02:35`. That's why you get `00:02`

You need to pass a `DateTime` object:

```
$datetime = [DateTimeOffset]::FromUnixTimeSeconds(1552912200).DateTime
Get-Date $datetime -UFormat '%R'
```